# How to escape a variable with a '.' in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, escaping

Im using ajax to make a request. As part of the request I get an ID which is in an nested json. Like so:

```
{"id": 1,"point": ["2016-10-13 09:05:53",85],"id": 1,"point": ["2016-10-13 09:05:53",85]}
```

I then use a `forEach` loop to get all the data:

```
success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(chartData) {
                var series = window.chart1.series[0],
            });   
        },
```

I want to use that ID in the json as a variable. So far I've tried:

```
var series = window.chart+chartData.id+.series[0]
```

but I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

When I input the ID directly:

```
var series = window.chart1.series[0],
```

it runs without any issue and if I console.log(chartData.id) I get the correct ID `1`.

How do I use the nested ID in the json as a variable?

Comment: You're probably using `window.chart1` variable before the value is assigned to it. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property accessing `[]` syntax.It will evaluate the expression and return to the `[]` the value.

```
var series = window['chart' + chartData.id].series[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this still get the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @kevinabraham Sorry . I have edited the answer.

Comment: thanks @suren-srapyan that worked! :). Will accept as soon as it allows me.